# spark program cannot locate hive-site.xml file

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to access hive data using Spark HiveContext. I have written the query "show databases". But the response I am getting is default.

Seems like my program is unable to locate hive-site.xml file placed in conf/ folder of my project and hence is creating a metastore_db in my project directory.

This is a sample code of what i m trying to do:

```
private static SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaSparkSQL").setMaster("local[*]");
private static JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

public static boolean runQuery() {

    JavaHiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.api.java.JavaHiveContext(ctx);



    List<Row> rows=sqlContext.sql("show databases").collect();
    for(Row row:rows){
        String i=row.getString(0);
        System.out.println("Response: "+i);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am not doing a spark submit. I am just calling runQuery(). How can i specify path for hive-site.xml in this code? Or is there any other way to read data from hive?

Comment: did you set your environment variables? SPARK_HOME ect...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the necessary Spark Environment variables in your .bash_profile (if in development) or whatever file you use for setting environment variables:

```
export SPARK_HOME=CHANGEME!!! 
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1 
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077 
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=9080 
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=$SPARK_HOME/../work 
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1 
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G 
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=2 
export SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=384m
... ect ect ect
```

There is probably a way to set all these using SparkConf setters, however I could not get these working.